# Duplicate value for one select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I m using select on my form. I collect values from my database. Select form show correct value but duplicate all values...

Example

> Aube Aube Aube Rhone Rhone Rhone Rhone Var Var ...

I just one 1 value of each if value is similar like :

> Aube Rhone Var

My code

```
<%= f.select :nomdep, Camping.all.collect { |p| [ p.nomdep ]}, include_blank: true %>
```

How fix this ? Thanks

Comment: try select distinct

Comment: I have a reply, thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<%= f.select :nomdep, Camping.order("nomdep ASC").pluck(:nomdep).uniq, include_blank: true %>
```

Comment: Really great. Thanks for your fast reply :)

Comment: By the way can I order by ASC ?

Comment: I have updated the code.Please tick the answer if it is helpful.

Comment: you made my day happy :) Thanks